# I can't find resources of this version of Assembly online

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

So I'm taking a Systems - Hardware class and in this class we're also learning about Assembly. Our professor gave us a simulator and it's documentation but  I can't find anything else about this version of Assembly outside the documentation.

Here is the link. https://asm-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. This may sound a stupid question but can you tell my which Assembly is this since of course I need more material and examples online but I'm struggling to find them even though I searched a lot.

Comment: Probably an imaginary CPU, just for educational purposes. The website contains full documentation, including links to Wikipedia articles to explain general assembly terms like 'logical left shift'. That's all there is. I guess your professor wants to stimulate your coding skills rather than your google skills.

Comment: Looking at the website it seems it contains already all information you are looking for, including further links.